# SQL query at least 3 are not equal for CHARs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am kinda new to mysql databases, and I wanted to verify that there exists a select statement for this problem before implementing my tables.

I would like to find a way in mysql to query some at least statements with strings.

**I would like to find: How many people watched at least three games that was not their favorite sport**

For example, let's say I have a table called Watcher.

Inside of it, we have Watcher ID and Favorite Sport such as football, soccer, baseball, and etc.

We also have a table called WeekWatched which is the 5 games he watched in the week. **Note: The watcher only watches 5 games a week.**

So our table would be:

Watcher ID, FavoriteSport  WatchedSport1, WatchedSport2, WatchedSport3, WatchedSport4, WatchedSport5.

Let's define our first watcher as someone who's favorite sport is baseball.

In WeekWatched, we have

**WatcherID , FavoriteSport, WatchedSport1,  WatchedSport2, WatchedSport3, WatchedSport 4,WatchedSport5**

1         ,  BaseBall,     Football, BaseBall,  Soccer,  Hockey,   Basketball

Does there exist an at least statment to query that the watcher watched at least 3 other sports than baseball?

**What I have done**: I have searched online and over stackoverflow. There were little resources that I found regarding at least statements with strings. I only found statements that dealt with numbers.

Comment: Dont have multiple columns having similar data. Instead, have a single column for favouritesport and store all the favourite sports in different rows

Comment: is there a working application behide this ? if not really follow @MadhurBhaiya 's suggestion ..

Comment: You would need to "unpivot" (convert columns into records with UNION ALL) the data, before you can use aggregate and COUNT() on it..

Comment: I have modified the question to make it more clear. @RaymondNijland, I have not made the working application yet. I was trying to see if this was possible before creating the database.

Comment: *"I have not made the working application yet. I was trying to see if this was possible before creating the database"* possible yes, unlogical yes and complex query: yes .. better you normalize to make it much more simple

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just learned about Normalization in class yesterday, so I definitely will try that as I do see watchedSport is a repeated column. However, i am still perplexed on how to query "at least 3 other sports than favorite". In general, I guess I am confused over how would I do the "at least" statement. Perhaps, I'll come back once I rethink about this again.

Comment: *"However, i am still perplexed on how to query "at least 3 other sports than favorite". In general, I guess I am confused over how would I do the "at least" statement. "* You still need to learn give it some time.. Take a look into [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/djGaEVRL8Ec3KZ6WNmdS3Y/6) and research how conditional aggregation works..